# How submit value of input field dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have some categories:

```
<div class="cbp-l-inline-title" style=" font-size: 18px;">
    <span style="color: #0669b4">Generic Name:</span> 
    <a><?php echo $category[0]['generic_name'];?></a>
</div>
```

and I want on click to insert value of this `<a>` to this form

```
<form method="post" action="/search/index" class="input-group" style="width: 45%; margin-left: 646px">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" minlength=3 placeholder="Generic" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <div id="suggesstion"></div>
    <div class="input-group-btn input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

so that it dynamically starts search of results of this string. I can't send this value to url because it is not latin characters

Comment: You will need to use JS if you want to start searching whenever the user types in the input field.

Comment: No i dont want them to type. when they click the link the value between <a>value</a> should go to input field SEARCH and submit

Comment: You still need to use JS: it handles all the scripting that occurs on the client side. What you want is to bind a click even to the `<a>` element, so that it injects the correct value into your input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html

```
<div class="cbp-l-inline-title" style=" font-size: 18px;">
  <span style="color: #0669b4">Generic Name:</span> 
  <p class="clickMe">click me: text to send after click</p>
</div>

<form method="post"  class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" minlength=3
                       placeholder="Generic" aria-label="Recipient's username"
                       aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div id="suggesstion"></div>
  <div class="input-group-btn input-group-append">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And javascript in jquery

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function(){
  var value = $(this).text()
  $('input#search').val(value)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ora0j4uu/

.submit() if you want submit it as well https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

**edit:**
jquery for submit

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function(){
  var value = $(this).text()
  console.log(value)
  $('input').val(value)
  $('.input-group').submit()
})
```

Comment: the code is working, but when i add .submit() it does the same. nothing changes